# Multiple ReactDOM.render() throwing error Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Trying to integrate React into a non-React project, so I need to able to render the react apps at multiple elements.

Here's the index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Activation from './forms/Activation';
import EditButton from '../components/editButton';

ReactDOM.render(<EditButton></EditButton>, document.getElementById('edit-button'));
ReactDOM.render(<Activation></Activation>, document.getElementById('activate-form'));
```

I am getting this [error](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=37):

```
_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

The first component, `EditButton`, does render successfully, but the second is unable too. If I move `Activation` to the top, then `Activation` will be the only component that renders.

Has anyone run into this issue? Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Because existing app isn't a SPA, depending on the route that user was on ('/' or '/product', etc.) the DOM element specified didn't exist. Fixed with just an if statement using getElementById, and if true ReactDOM.render().

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if script finds the second element. You can check it with something like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('activate-form'))
console.log(document.getElementById('edit-button'))
```

Also, check if there is only one element with each id exists on the page. And finally if this elements are not nested.

Comment: So the second log will return null.

There is only one element of both id's. 

Not quite sure what you mean by 'if this elements are not nested'. Both elements are nested within multiple divs.

Comment: @JohnSon I mean that elements must not be nested by each other. If the second log returns null then you should find the issue in html. May be wrong character in id, may be unclosed html tag or something else. Also you can check html structure in browser devtools. The second element should exist after React renders the first component.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The issue was that depending on which route the user was on '/' or '/product' etc. the dom element didn't exist like you suggested. 

Coming from react to a non SPA app, didn't see this as a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes a good practice to make sure the DOM element exists:

```js
if ( document.getElementById('root') ) {

    ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById('root'));

}
```